# ReferenceError: AbortController is not defined at fetchCSSFromGoogleFonts

Tags: next.js, next.js13

Today, I upgraded to next 13.3 from 13.1.6, and migrated my Google fonts to `next/font/google`. However, I am getting an error while building on Vercel. I have already checked the changes in the production build by running `npm run build` and `npm run start` and it's working fine, but it's failing on vercel.

```js
import { Inter } from "next/font/google"

const inter = Inter({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  variable: "--font-inter",
})

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
        
          <div className={`${inter.variable} font-sans`}>
            {renderWithLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}
          </div>
  )
}
```

Error Message:

```bash
ReferenceError: AbortController is not defined
    at fetchCSSFromGoogleFonts (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/font/dist/google/fetch-css-from-google-fonts.js:34:28)
    at nextFontGoogleFontLoader (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/font/dist/google/loader.js:76:79)
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-font-loader/index.js:60:99
    at Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:26)
    at Object.nextFontLoader (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-font-loader/index.js:13:31)
    at LOADER_EXECUTION (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/loader-runner/LoaderRunner.js:1:4134)
    at runSyncOrAsync (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/loader-runner/LoaderRunner.js:1:4145)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/loader-runner/LoaderRunner.js:1:5782)
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/loader-runner/LoaderRunner.js:1:5426
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:28:395994
Failed to compile.
src/pages/_app.js
`next/font` error:
Failed to fetch `Inter` from Google Fonts.
> Build failed because of webpack errors
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
Deployment completed
BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

I'm not using `AbortController` anywhere in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporarily you can downgrade into v13.2.3 which works as expected.